# SNMP differences in ifInOctets vs ifHCInOctets values

Tags: networking, linux-networking, snmp

I'm trying to graph network usage on my router for a specific interface using data from SNMP. I know that ifInOctets/ifOutOctets is only 32 bit and will overflow for high speeds and make my graphs look dumb, but it looks like the differences in values returned by ifInOctets/ifOutOctets and ifHCInOctets/ifHCOutOctets aren't always identical. I've tested a few times by using `snmpwalk | grep InOctets` and subtracting the values. Sometimes I see that the change in the 32-bit counter is significantly less (more than 50%) than the change in the 64-bit version, and sometimes I see it go the other way with the 64-bit counter showing a smaller delta.

Am I missing something in the way that the 64-bit counters should be read, or is there just a difference in how their data gets updated? The 32-bit numbers match up with what's in /proc/net/dev, so I'm inclined to believe them more, but the wrapping issue makes them unusable when the speed gets too high:

[image: dumb graphs with rollover]

Here are a few examples, each snmpwalk was run about 10 seconds apart:

```
$ snmpwalk  -c public -v2c 192.168.1.1 | grep -i InOctets.2
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 2291487255
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.2 = Counter64: 2901400127083

$ snmpwalk  -c public -v2c 192.168.1.1 | grep -i InOctets.2
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 2297202283
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.2 = Counter64: 2901400298056
```

32-bit change: 5715028

64-bit change: 170973

```
$ snmpwalk  -c public -v2c 192.168.1.1 | grep -i InOctets.2
IF-MIB::ifInOctets.2 = Counter32: 2297528566
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.2 = Counter64: 2901400453366
```

32-bit change: 326283

64-bit change: 155310

Comment: Which version of SNMP protocol are you using? SNMP V2C and V3 has 64 bit support.

Comment: Currently using v2c

Comment: What kind of router are you using? Is it Linux based? Which distribution is it running?

Comment: Asus RT-AC66U, running asuswrt-merlin

Comment: May be you just hit a bug, like this one: https://sourceforge.net/p/net-snmp/bugs/2741/

Comment: With a gigabit interface running at full speed, the 32-bit counters can roll over in about 40 seconds, so I'm still suspicious that rollover might be biting you.  Could you **show** us the problem?  Show us the output from that `snmpwalk|grep InOctets` at two fairly-close times, so that we can **see** the difference between the changes in 32-bit and 64-bit stats?

Comment: Updated with a few examples. Also I don't think the 32 bit counter is always rolling over that often. I added an example of when I do see the rollover in my graph, so it's pretty obvious when it happens.

Comment: I agree with you, plus the 64-bit values don't give any reason to suspect rollover, either.  That is downright weird, and might have to be addressed to Asus.

Answer (score 1):

RFC 2233 adopted expanded 64-bit counters for high capacity interfaces in which 32-bit counters do not provide enough capacity and wrap too fast.

https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/26007-faq-snmpcounter.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you shouldn't run over **whole** tree of SNMP OIDs, it takes a significant amount of time. Could you try `snmpbulkwalk  -c public -v2c 192.168.1.1 InOctets.2` and `snmpbulkwalk  -c public -v2c 192.168.1.1 ifHCInOctets.2` instead?
But anyway, that difference looks weird. Do you have other SNMP devices to compare with?

Comment: You could also use `snmpget` on both values at once to get an atomic view.